# LIKE % is not recognized in createQuery("") but is working in @Query("")

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, graphql

When I try to do ,
This works and RETURNS ME A LIST

```
@Repository{   
public interface CustomerRepository extends JPARepository<CustomerEntity,Long>{
    @Query("select c from Customer c where c.custName LIKE %:custName% ORDER BY AGE DESC"
    List<CustomerEntity> fetchAllCustomer(String custname);
}
```

But when I try to do :
result1 -->returns a list ,
result 2 --> ERROR : java.lang.illegealArguments: org.hibernate.gql.internal.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token : % near line 1 , column 112

```
public class CustomerResolver implements GraphQlQueryResolver{
  @PersistaneUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public List<CustomerType> findCustomer(String search){
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

  List<CustomerType> result1 = (List<CustomerType>)em.createQuery("select c from Customer c ORDER BY AGE 
  DESC").setMAXResults(3).getResultList();
  System.out.println(result1);

  List<CustomerType> result2 = (List<CustomerType>)em.createQuery("select c from Customer c where  
  c.custName LIKE %:custName% ORDER BY AGE 
  DESC").setParameter("custName",search).setMAXResults(3).getResultList();
  System.out.println(result2);

  ...code
  ...code
  ...return ...
  

  
}
}
```

Is it that  the createQuery doesn't take up % for LIKE , but does work for @Query???????
Or am  I missing out something ???

Kind Regards,
Kasis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my example please check

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%') ORDER BY AGE DESC")
List<String> findUsersWithPartOfName(@Param("username") String username);
```

Comment: List<CustomerType> result2 = (List<CustomerType>)em.createQuery("select c from Customer c where  
  c.custName LIKE CONCAT('%',:custName,'%') ORDER BY AGE 
  DESC").setParameter("custName",search).setMAXResults(3).getResultList();

CONCAT did the Trick @Zaur . 
Thanks mate!!!